# The curve segments $y=e^x$ for $0\leq x \leq 1$ and $y = \ln(x)$ for $1 \leq x \leq e$ have the same length.

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

The curve segments $y=e^x$ for $0\leq x \leq 1$ and $y = \ln(x)$ for $1 \leq x \leq e$ have the same length. Prove or disprove. I got the idea that they are inverse functions and probably we can show that the length are equal by showing the symmetry on graph, so I am curious how actually I can prove this without  graph, maybe using the notation of inverse function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the length of the curve $y=e^x$ from 0 to 1 is

$$L_1 = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} dx = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+e^{2x}} dx$$

The curve $y=\ln{x}$ can be written as $x=e^y$ as a function of *y*. The length of this curve from *x* = 1 to *e* (or, equivalently, *y* = 0 to 1) is

$$L_2 = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2} dy = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+e^{2y}} dy$$

So they can be expressed by the same integral, just with different variables.

Answer (score 1):

The two arcs are congruent, i.e., isometric as subsets of the euclidean plane $E:={\mathbb R}^2$. Therefore under any  definition of arc length  in $E$ (integral, sup of sums of inscribed segment lengths, etc.) they have the same length.

Comment: Sorry Sir, but I dont understand this proof since I did not study congruences as subsets, may be there is simplier proof.

Comment: @YahyaRafiyev: Maybe the fact that the map $(x,y)\to(y,x)$ is an isometry helps.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = e^x, 0 \le x \le 1$  and $g(x) = \ln (x), 1 \le x \le e$  are inverse functions of each other. that is if draw the two graphs then they are mirror images of each other on the mirror $y = x.$ therefore both curves have the same length.